# How to determine whether the DHCP function is enabled? I can not get any solution to solve my problem

Tags: java, android

I have a device ,it is android system.
I need to determine whether DHCP is enabled for the device or whether the IP address of the device is static.
I have not find a good method to solve my problem.
My device can gain IP by WIFI and Network cable.

Comment: If it was static and it was for example 192.168.0.12 the device could not connect to wifi or lan with gateway 192.168.9.## and so on.

Comment: I don't quite understand.Is there any specific code that can tell whether it is a static IP or a dynamic IP?